# How do I crop the selected part of an image with a preset size (800*400px)?

Tags: php, crop

I am trying to create a form for adding a post with the specified image size of 800*400px.

800px constant width, 400px maximum height of the final image, i.e. less than 400 is allowed.

The minimum allowed size of a photo uploaded to crop is 800x400

[Demonstration](https://bemall.org/news/add/) of what is available in the "Select image" field.

Now you can upload an image, select a place for a crop and perform a crop, but the result will be sad, because the proportions of the image are not saved.

For example, the original image may be 1920*1152px

[image]

After crop the selected part, the result is as follows

[image]

I am trying to create a form for adding a post with the specified image size of 800*400px.

800px constant width, 400px maximum height of the final image, i.e. less than 400 is allowed.

The minimum allowed size of a photo uploaded to crop is 800x400

Demonstration of what is available in the "Select image" field.

Now you can upload an image, select a place for a crop and perform a crop, but the result will be sad, because the proportions of the image are not saved.

For example, the original image may be 1920*1152px enter an image description here

After crop the selected part, the result is as follows enter an image description here

I need the result that is highlighted in the crop editor with a maximum size of 800*400 or 800 or less than 400, depending on the source image, so that it is saved proportionally.

This editor I spied on one of the sites, where only 2 parameters are sent to the server at the time of crop, the **url** of the image preloaded on the server and the parameter **y**-apparently the starting point from the upper-left corner. I repeated the same thing in [my example](https://bemall.org/news/add/).

**Example**: `{"url":"https://site.ru/news/upload_tmp/files/file.jpg","y":"81"}`

I found a similar script, tried a lot of different settings, but couldn't get the result.

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{

$postData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($postData, true);

$url = $data["url"];
$y = $data["y"];

$_POST['x1'] = '0';
$_POST['x2'] = '800';
$_POST['y'] = $y;
$_POST['y2'] = '400';
$_POST['img'] = $url;
$_POST['crop'] = 'files/';



/**
* Zoom image
*
* Функция работает с PNG, GIF и JPEG изображениями.
* Масштабирование возможно как с указаниями одной стороны, так и двух, в процентах или пикселях.
*
* @param string Расположение исходного файла
* @param string Расположение конечного файла
* @param integer Ширина конечного файла
* @param integer Высота конечного файла
* @param bool Размеры даны в пискелях или в процентах
* @return bool
*/

function resize($file_input, $file_output, $w_o, $h_o, $percent = false) {
list($w_i, $h_i, $type) = getimagesize($file_input);
if (!$w_i || !$h_i) {
echo 'It is not possible to get the length and width of the image';
return;
}
$types = array('','gif','jpeg','png');
$ext = $types[$type];
if ($ext) {
$func = 'imagecreatefrom'.$ext;
$img = $func($file_input);
} else {
echo 'Invalid file format';
return;
}
if ($percent) {
$w_o *= $w_i / 100;
$h_o *= $h_i / 100;
}
if (!$h_o) $h_o = $w_o/($w_i/$h_i);
if (!$w_o) $w_o = $h_o/($h_i/$w_i);
$img_o = imagecreatetruecolor($w_o, $h_o);
imagecopyresampled($img_o, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w_o, $h_o, $w_i, $h_i);
if ($type == 2) {
imagejpeg($img_o,$file_output,100);
} else {
$func = 'image'.$ext;
$func($img_o,$file_output);
}
imagedestroy($img_o);
}

/**
* Cropping an image
*
* Функция работает с PNG, GIF и JPEG изображениями.
* Обрезка идёт как с указанием абсолютной длины, так и относительной (отрицательной).
*
* @param string Расположение исходного файла
* @param string Расположение конечного файла
* @param array Координаты обрезки
* @param bool Размеры даны в пискелях или в процентах
* @return bool
*/
function crop($file_input, $file_output, $crop = 'square',$percent = false) {
list($w_i, $h_i, $type) = getimagesize($file_input);
if (!$w_i || !$h_i) {
echo 'It is not possible to get the length and width of the image';
return;
}
$types = array('','gif','jpeg','png');
$ext = $types[$type];
if ($ext) {
$func = 'imagecreatefrom'.$ext;
$img = $func($file_input);
} else {
echo 'Invalid file format';
return;
}
if ($crop == 'square') {
$min = $w_i;
if ($w_i > $h_i) $min = $h_i;
$w_o = $h_o = $min;
} else {
list($x_o, $y_o, $w_o, $h_o) = $crop;
if ($percent) {
    $w_o *= $w_i / 100;
    $h_o *= $h_i / 100;
    $x_o *= $w_i / 100;
    $y_o *= $h_i / 100;
}
if ($w_o < 0) $w_o += $w_i;
$w_o -= $x_o;
if ($h_o < 0) $h_o += $h_i;
$h_o -= $y_o;
}
$img_o = imagecreatetruecolor($w_o, $h_o);
imagecopy($img_o, $img, 0, 0, $x_o, $y_o, $w_o, $h_o);
if ($type == 2) {
imagejpeg($img_o,$file_output,100);

} else {
$func = 'image'.$ext;
$func($img_o,$file_output);
}
imagedestroy($img_o);
}



function prov($per){
if (isset($per)) {
$per = stripslashes($per);
$per = htmlspecialchars($per);
$per = addslashes($per);         
}
return $per;
}

if(isset($_POST)){
$filenew = 'main.png'; // rewritable main.png

$x1 = prov($_POST['x1']);
$x2 = prov($_POST['x2']);
$y = prov($_POST['y']);
$y2 = prov($_POST['y2']);
$img = prov($_POST['img']);
$crop = prov($_POST['crop']);

crop($img, $crop.$filenew, array($x1, $y, $x2, $y2));   

//echo $filenew;
echo '{"result":"ok","data":"https:\/\/site.ru\/news\/cropImage\/files\/' . $filenew . '"}';

}

}else{
print '{"result":"error","message":"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0438\u0437\u043e\u0448\u043b\u0430 \u043e\u0448\u0438\u0431\u043a\u0430 \u0432\u043e \u0432\u0440\u0435\u043c\u044f \u0441\u043e\u0445\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f"}';
}
```

I set up the default parameters differently (all except $url and $y), found more or less decent options, but all the wrong ones :(

Perhaps you have encountered a similar task and can help me understand this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered an image manipulation library like [this](https://github.com/Intervention/image)?

Comment: Not. Now I will study the library. Thank!